# If $A$ is open then $\text{Int}(A)=A$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $A$ any subset of $X$. The largest open set contained in $A$ is called the interior of $A$ and is denoted $\text{Int}(A)$.
>
> i$)$ Show that if $A$ is open in $(X,\tau)$ then $\text{Int}(A)=A$,

**My attempt**:
$a\in A$ there exists an open set $a\in\mathscr{U}_a$.

$\text{Int}(A)=\bigcup_{a\in A}\mathscr{U_a},\forall \mathscr{U}_a\subset A$.

Let's define $A'=A\cup\mathscr{U}_x$ such that $\mathscr{U}_x\nsubseteq A$, so $A'\supset A$, however since $\mathscr{U}_x\nsubseteq A$, then $\mathscr{U}_x\nsubseteq \text{Int}(A)$.

**Question:**

Is my proof right? If not Why? What are alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with this proof. It begins with “$a\in A$ there exists an open set $a\in\mathscr{U}_a$.” Well, this is not a sentence. What do you mean? That, for each $a\in A$, there is an open set $O$ such that $a\in O$? Sure: take $O=X$. Or, since $A$ is open, take $O=A$.

The second sentence (?) makes no sense either.

It always happens that $\mathring A\subset A$. On the other hand, if $A$ is open and if $a\in A$, then $A$ is an open subset of $X$ which is a subset of $A$ and to which $a$ belongs. Since $\mathring A$ is the union of all such subsets of $X$, $a\in\mathring A$. So, this proves that $A\subset\mathring A$. And, since $A\supset\mathring A$, $A=\mathring A$.

Comment: Regarding the first sentence. If I specified $\mathscr{U}_a\subset A$. Would it solve the problem that you are referring?

Comment: Which is the second sentence? My definition of interior?

Comment: @PedroGomes Yes. I hadn't realised that it was your definition of interior. And it is meaningless.

Comment: Could you explain me why?

Comment: @PedroGomes No, I cannot explain why I see no meaning in it. Perhaps that you could tell me what is it that that expression means to you.

Comment: If I consider $\mathscr{U}_a$ to be the smallest open set containing  an arbitrary point $a$, then $Int(A)=\bigcup_{a\in A}\mathscr{U}_a$. I can find it for all $a\in A$. What is failing in this definition? I would like to correct it.

Comment: In general, there is no such thing as “the smallest open set containing an arbitrary point $a$”. What would be, say, the smallest open subset of $\mathbb R$ containing $0$?

Comment: Right! What is the definition of interior?

Comment: The interior of $A$ is the set of all $a\in X$ such that $A$ is a neighbourhood of $a$. This is the same thing as saying that $\mathring A$ is the set of all $a\in X$ for which there is an open subset $O$ of $X$ such that $x\in O$ and that $O\subset A$.

Comment: Thanks for your support! Now I understood the importance of using neighbourhood.

Answer (score 2):

If your definition of the interior of a subset $A$ is

> the largest open set contained in $A$

it is a tautology that if $A$ is an open set, it is its own interior.

Comment: Would my definition then suffice as a proof?

Comment: In my opinion, yes. But is it the usual definition?

Comment: No, it is my definition.

Answer (score 1):

> "....The largest open set contained in $A$ is called the interior of $A$ and is denoted $\text{int}(A)$."

If $A$ is open then it is an open set that is contained in $A$.

Secondly there is no set $B$ that satisfies both the conditionss

- 1) $B\subseteq A$
- 2) $B$ is properly larger than $A$ in the sense that $A\subsetneq B$

So we conclude that $A$ is the *largest* open set that is contained in $A$, i.e. $A=\text{int}(A)$.